# Issue with dictionary values not appending in Django session

Tags: django, dictionary, django-views

I'm encountering an issue with updating dictionary values in Django session. Initially, I was using a list to store data in the session, and it worked perfectly fine. However, when I switched to using a dictionary to store the data, I noticed that the values were not getting appended as expected. Instead, the new data was replacing the old data in the dictionary.

**views.py:**

```
def pushups(request):
    if "record" not in request.session or not isinstance(request.session["record"], dict):
        request.session["record"] = {}

    return render(request, ("App_4/record.html"), {
        "record" : request.session["record"]
    })

def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Add_record_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            a = form.cleaned_data["add_form"]
            b = request.session["record"]
            b[f"{date.year}-{date.month}-{date.day} {date.hour}:{date.minute}:{date.second}"] = a
            request.session["record"] = b
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("App_4:view_record"))
        else:
            return render(request, "App_4/add_record.html", {
                "add_form" : form
            })
    return render(request, ("App_4/add_record.html"), {
        "add_form" : Add_record_form()
    })
```

**record.html**

```
    {% for key,value in record.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{value}}</td>
        </tr> 
    {% empty %}
        <tr>
            <td>no tasks</td>
        </tr>    
    {% endfor %}
```

The strange thing is that the dictionary values only get updated correctly if I make changes in the views.py file or just simply click CTRL+S before adding new data. Otherwise, the previous data just gets replaced. This issue wasn't present when I was using a list instead of a dictionary.

I think the problem has something to do with this particular part:

```
b = request.session["record"]
b[f"{date.year}-{date.month}-{date.day} {date.hour}:{date.minute}:{date.second}"] = a
request.session["record"] = b
```

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It was a dumb mistake. The date was not getting updated because "date" was a global variable, and as it was used as the key in the dictionary, it kept replacing the old data with the same key. Creating a date variable inside the "add" function solved the issue.

Here's the modified version of the code:

```
date = datetime.now()
b = request.session.get("record", {})
b[f"{date.year}-{date.month}-{date.day} {date.hour}:{date.minute}: 
 {date.second}"] = a
request.session["record"] = b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `request.session.modified = True` and see if it helps.

```
b = request.session.get("record", {})
b[f"{date.year}-{date.month}-{date.day} {date.hour}:{date.minute}:{date.second}"] = a
request.session["record"] = b
request.session.modified = True  # Mark the session as modified
```

Doc related to this answer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work.